# Battery drain issue with background location service

Tags: android, geolocation, battery

My app is used, amongst other features, for tracking drivers doing delivery work, so we need to track the driver's location constantly. For that, we use a Service that runs in the background and saves the coordinates internally before we send them to a server.

The problem is, as is expected, the more precise we need to get, the more the battery drain increases. To the point where Google Play Console Vitals is showing a way above the average number for wake ups like this:
*walarm*:com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR*

I want to know if I'm doing something wrong or if the only way I can improve the code is by doing minor tweaks.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private Integer gpsFreqInMillis = 1000 * 10; //10 seconds
    private Integer gpsFreqInDistance = 10; //10 meters
    ...

    public void startUpdatingLocation() {

        ...


        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, gpsFreqInMillis, gpsFreqInDistance, this);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, gpsFreqInMillis, gpsFreqInDistance, this);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location newLocation) {
        //saves location in internal database
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can track a precise location without killing my user's battery? I know I can change the min distance and min time values, but 10m/10s is the most precise option we offer.

Comment: Use JobService For start Location Service

Comment: @GaneshPokale how will that help?  Ty

Answer (score 0):

Only way around to fix this is to optimize the request callbacks by updating these values in your code to

```
private Integer gpsFreqInMillis = 1000 * 40; //10 seconds
private Integer gpsFreqInDistance = 20; //10 meters
```

Comment: There will be some delay but that will be okay in real time

Comment: That is configurable already in my system, it helps, but in the most precise case still doesn't change much.